# ruby fill data in chart.js

Tags: ruby, charts

I'm new in ruby programming and I am sticky
I would like to copy data from mesdata to data in data table.

```
data = [
         {
             data: Array.new(4) {},
             backgroundColor: [
                               '#F7464A',
                               '#46BFBD',
                               '#FDB45C',
                               '#32CD32',
                              ],
             hoverBackgroundColor: [
                               '#FF6384',
                               '#36A2EB',
                               '#FFCE56',
                               '#00FF00',
                              ],
        },
]

mesdata = [10,20,20,40]
```

Comment: I'm a little unclear. What output do you want? Try `data[0][:data] = mesdata` to see if that's close.

Comment: Thank's a lot. I was looking complicated things and it was so easy.